# Retrieving webmethod parameter values from Application_BeginRequest or Application_EndRequest

Tags: .net, asp.net, soap, httpwebrequest, asmx

Is there a way to retrieving parameter names and values passed to a web method from Request object? I've read somewhere that you need extra code to access the soap body. Any known workarounds to be able to see the soap body from Application_BeginRequest?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If these events fired in this case you can read the xml content of the request by calling :

```
Request.InputStream.Read(...);
```

and then :

```
 Request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

to reset the InputStream location.

Answer (score 1):

ASMX web services do not use the full ASP.NET pipeline. I don't believe that these two events even fire for a web service.

To access the SOAP data stream, you want to implement a [SoapExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.aspx).

---

Of course, I should also take this opportunity to remind readers that Microsoft now considers ASMX web services to be a "legacy technology". They suggest that all new web service development should use WCF.

Comment: Thanks John.  I am aware of WCF being the replacement to the good ol' web services. However you are mistaken regarding the Application_BeginRequest & Application_EndRequest not being invoked in from asmx. They are indeed being invoked properly by the web server. The question I have is how to "pull" the soap information out from the Request object, the debugger breaks there but the object has too much stuff embedded and I cannot seem to find the soap body.

Comment: @Ash: I'm glad the events fire, but there's no place to get the body from. How would you get the HTTP request body of a "normal" HTTP request in a "normal" ASP.NET application?

Comment: After alot of researching, the only way possible was to write my own SoapExtension class to get to the soap xml message